# SQ-universality and short exact sequence

Tags: gr.group-theory, short-exact-sequences

> Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Assume that $G$ decomposes as a short exact sequence
> $$1 \to N \to G \to A \to 1$$
> where $A$ is free abelian and $N$ SQ-universal. Is $G$ SQ-universal?

A group $G$ is *SQ-universal* if, for every countable group $Q$, there exists some normal subgroup $M \lhd G$ such that $G/M$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $Q$.

The answer seems to be positive in many cases. For instance, if $A= \mathbb{Z}$ and if $N$ is hyperbolic, then $G$ must be SQ-universal. However, I guess that the answer should be negative in full generality.

**Remark:** When $N$ is acylindrically hyperbolic (a property known to imply being SQ-universal), the answer is often positive. Indeed, there is a natural morphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ whose image contains $\mathrm{Inn}(N)$. But I conjecture that the automorphism group of a finitely generated (presented?) acylindrically hyperbolic group is acylindrically hyperbolic itself. (For instance, this is known for (relatively) hyperbolic groups, right-angled Artin groups and right-angled Coxeter groups.) When this is true, the image of $G$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ must be acylindrically hyperbolic, implying that $G$ is SQ-universal.

Comment: Unless you're implicitly assuming that $N$ is finitely generated, the question boils down to the case when $A$ is infinite cyclic.

Comment: No, I am not assuming that $N$ is finitely generated.

Comment: OK (but my claim that it reduces to cyclic quotient is not true, or at least not obvious, since $G$ is supposed f.g.). What's true is that the analogous question for arbitrary groups (with $A$ assumed f.g.), or for countable groups, reduces to the case when $A$ is infinite cyclic.

Comment: Do you know if free-by-cyclic groups are SQ-universal (by your last statement, yes for (f.g. free)-by-cyclic are. (Of course I'm assuming free not abelian in the previous sentence.)

Comment: If the free group is not finitely generated, I don't really know.